# Mostrar valor de un struct

Tags: c++, struct

estoy teniendo un problema que probablemente sea una tontería pero no comprendo porque no funciona a pesar de su sencillez.

Teniendo un `struct` compuesto por las componentes de un vector en 3D, sólo quería mostrar por pantalla una de ellas después de haberla tecleado y sin embargo me muestra un valor gigantesco:

```
struct vector3D
{
    double x, y, z;
};

int main()
{
    vector3D v;

    printf("Introduce las tres componentes de un vector3D");
    printf("\nComp. 1: ");   scanf("%f", &v.x);
    printf("Comp. 2: ");   scanf("%f", &v.y);
    printf("Comp. 3: ");   scanf("%f", &v.z);

    printf("%f", v.x); // Aquí muestra un valor que no tiene nada que ver con lo 
                       // que he tecleado previamente y me impide hacer otros cálculos

return 0;
}
```

No sé si es que he declarado algo mal o qué. Aprecio vuestra atención. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Esto es C o C++?

Comment: Es C++, lo había puesto en el título y en las etiquetas

Comment: Es C++, pero parece totalmente C...

Comment: @NaCl La etiqueta C++ se salva porque ese código no compila en C por la declaración de la variable basada en el `struct`

Comment: Hacer uso de `printf` o `scanf` en C++ no es una buena práctica. En dicho lenguaje existen `cout` y `cin`.

Comment: @eferion Había olvidado totalmente que en C++ se puede definir una variable de tipo `struct` sin utilizar esa palabra clave, sin embargo, es totalmente aplicable a ambos lenguajes :^)

Comment: En C no puedes hacer `vector3D v;` si no has hecho antes `typedef struct { /* ... */ } vector3D;`

Comment: por favor, la respuesta que mejor solucione tu problema márcala como solución. Así pones tu granito de arena en lo que a mantenimiento de StackOverflow se refiere. Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

Como no se ha especificado si el lenguaje es C o C++, voy con ambas :^)!

Así cómo tal, el código que nos das no debería ni compilar *(En C)*, o como mínimo, arrojar unas 8 advertencias y unos 3 errores *(Eh que he dicho los números de cabeza)*.

Para empezar, utilizas `printf` y `scanf` sin haber hecho un `#include <stdio.h>` *(Para [c](/questions/tagged/c))* o un `#include <cstdio>` *(Para [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b))*.

### Parte de la respuesta para [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

El problema principal, es que estás usando `%f` como especificador de formato, cuando deberías usar `%lf` y por eso estás viendo valores *extraños*.

### Parte de la respuesta para [c](/questions/tagged/c):

Primero, defines una `struct`, sin embargo no declaras ninguna variable de tipo `struct vector3D`, te recomendaría cambiar tu definicion de `struct vector3D` a:

```
typedef struct VECTOR3D {
    double x, y, z;
} vector3D;
```

Con ese simple cambio, tu código debería ser capáz de funcionar, aunque, si no quieres cambiar la definición de tu `struct`, sólo cambia la siguiente línea en tu función `main()`:

```
vector3D v;
```

Por:

```
struct vector3D v;
```

Para poder utilizar la variable `v` sin problemas, esto pasa porque C utiliza `struct <NOMBRE>` como *etiqueta*, permitiendo utilizar el nombre de la estructura en otras cosas siempre que no le pongamos el prefijo `struct` para definir una variable de tipo `struct <NOMBRE>` *(Donde  es un nombre de tu preferencia)*, el `typedef` es para decirle al compilador que tu `struct` debe ser tratado como un tipo y que por ende, permita la definición de variables con el nombre del tipo, que usualmente está colocado al final de la definición de la `struct`.

El código final quedaría de la siguiente forma *(Funciona para ambos C y C++)*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct vector3D
{
    double x, y, z;
};

int main()
{
    struct vector3D v;

    printf("Introduce las tres componentes de un vector3D");
    printf("\nComp. 1: ");   scanf("%f", &v.x);
    printf("Comp. 2: ");   scanf("%f", &v.y);
    printf("Comp. 3: ");   scanf("%f", &v.z);

    printf("%lf\n", v.x);
    return 0;
}
```

Me he tomado la libertad de probar tu código y esta es la salida que obtengo:

```
Introduce las tres componentes de un vector3D
Comp. 1: 2
Comp. 2: 3
Comp. 3: 1
2.000000
```

*Notese que he puesto `2, 3, 1` como entrada.*

Saludos :)

Comment: Sí, por supuesto he obviado la declaración de la librería por ahorrar código al publicar la pregunta aquí, pensaba que se sobreentendería. Agradezco mucho tu respuesta, no creía que el "%lf" fuera necesario porque pensaba que el %f ya valía. En cuanto a lo del struct, lo tendré en cuenta de ahora en adelante, pero me había sorprendido porque recuerdo haber hecho ejercicios en los que hacía las declaraciones de la misma manera que he publicado al principio (sin typedefs) y me permitían hacer de todo correctamente. En fin, empezaré a usarlo y muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: En C++, lo del `struct` no es problema, pero en C sí lo es, por ello he puesto ambas partes :P, sin embargo, siempre es mejor ser precabidos y esperar que cualquiera pueda compilar el código :)

Comment: Sí, esto lo hago para clase y usamos C++ pero tengo que limitarme a la librería stdio.h. Tocamos temas mucho más avanzados que este que he expuesto pero me ha sorprendido muchísimo encontrarme con este error básico, que no me había ocurrido nunca.

Answer (score 3):

Si estás programando en C++ no uses `printf` ni `scanf` sino `cin` y `cout`:

```
int main()
{
    vector3D v;

    std::cout << "Introduce las tres componentes de un vector3D\n";
    std::cout "Comp. 1: ";
    std::cin >> v.x;
    std::cout "Comp. 2: ";
    std::cin >> v.y;
    std::cout "Comp. 3: ";
    std::cin >> v.z;

    std::cout << v.x;

    return 0;
}
```

Pero... ¿por qué falla?

Como te comenta [@NaCl](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/133043/463) el problema se produce porque estás configurando `scanf` para que lea `float` en vez de `double` ... ¿Cómo de importante es este detallito?

Pues veamos:

- [`double`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double) tiene 52 bits de mantisa, 11 bits de exponente y 1 bit de signo.
- [`float`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) tiene 23 bits de mantisa, 8 bits de exponente y 1 bit de signo.

Expresado de forma gráfica quedaría así:

```
float   S E E E E E E E E M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M
double  S E E E E E E E E E E E M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M M ..... M
```

Entonces, si tu almacenas en un `double` un dato `float` sin hacer conversiones sucede lo siguiente:

```
float   0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
double  0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 M M M M M ..... M
```

Nota que las `M` restantes del `double` no ven alterado su valor y contendrán basura... que es lo que te falsea el resultado obtenido al imprimir el número de vuelta.

Así que, como te he comentado nada más iniciar la respuesta... si programas en C++ haz uso de las características propias de C++.

Comment: Pero yo pensaba que el %f se usaba específicamente para "double", acaso hay otro especificador de formato específico para él?? En cuanto a lo del cout y cin ya sé que a veces son más cómodos pero sigo usando siempre stdio.h por costumbre y para manejar ficheros y esas cosas...

Comment: @Laura No lo he mencionado porque ya lo ha explicado @NaCl... si sigues empeñada (o te obligan a ello) en usar `scanf` tienes que usar el modificador `"%lf"`. Haciendo uso de las clases de `C++` te desentiendes de este tipo de detalles porque será el compilador el que llame a la función adecuada en cada momento.

Comment: @Laura por otro lado no te empeñes en usar `stdio.h` por costumbre... así nunca aprenderás C++ y no podrás sacarle todo el partido. Para ficheros tienes también clases estupendas en C++ que pueden trabajar incluso más rápido que sus homólogas de C

Comment: @Laura cuando usas la función `printf`, creo que `%f` se convierte a `double` automáticamente, sin embargo, `scanf` trabaja con sus respectivos tipos, `%f` y `%lf`... es mejor hacerlo como ha dicho @eferion, si trabajas en C++, mejor `cin` y `cout`, siempre!

Comment: Sí, soy consciente de que algunas cosas se hacen más eficientemente de otros modos, pero me obligan a usar únicamente <stdio.h> (quizá no lo había mencionado antes) aunque ya sé que la librería <iostream> te da el cin y el cout y que C++ permite manejar ficheros de otra forma etc. etc. Muchas gracias, ya ha quedado claro